# Unable to install wordpress theme without ftp user & password

Tags: installation

I have just installed wordpress, and I would like to also install a theme.
Unfortunately I am asked for an FTP username and password, when trying to install it from the admin interface.

As I understand this is only the case if the 'wp-content' is not writeable. However in my case this folder is writable:

Wordpress installed in /var/www/html/wp/, and these are the permissions:

Permissions for /var/www/html/wp:

```
drwxrwsr-x 5 wordpress www-data  4096 Oct 26 09:30 wp
```

Permissions for the content of /var/www/html/wp:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 wordpress www-data   418 Sep 25  2013 index.php
-rw-r--r--  1 wordpress www-data 19935 Jan  2  2017 license.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 wordpress www-data  7413 Dec 12  2016 readme.html
-rw-r--r--  1 wordpress www-data  5447 Sep 27  2016 wp-activate.php
drwxr-sr-x  9 wordpress www-data  4096 Sep 19 21:21 wp-admin
-rw-r--r--  1 wordpress www-data   364 Dec 19  2015 wp-blog-header.php
-rw-r--r--  1 wordpress www-data  1627 Aug 29  2016 wp-comments-post.php
-rw-r--r--  1 wordpress www-data  3138 Oct 26 09:28 wp-config.php
-rw-r--r--  1 wordpress www-data  2853 Dec 16  2015 wp-config-sample.php
drwxrwsrwx  6 www-data  www-data  4096 Oct 29 22:38 wp-content
-rw-r--r--  1 wordpress www-data  3286 May 24  2015 wp-cron.php
drwxr-sr-x 18 wordpress www-data 12288 Sep 19 21:21 wp-includes
-rw-r--r--  1 wordpress www-data  2422 Nov 21  2016 wp-links-opml.php
-rw-r--r--  1 wordpress www-data  3301 Oct 29 22:38 wp-load.php
-rw-r--r--  1 wordpress www-data 34327 May 12 17:12 wp-login.php
-rw-r--r--  1 wordpress www-data  8048 Jan 11  2017 wp-mail.php
-rw-r--r--  1 wordpress www-data 16200 Apr  6  2017 wp-settings.php
-rw-r--r--  1 wordpress www-data 29924 Jan 24  2017 wp-signup.php
-rw-r--r--  1 wordpress www-data  4513 Oct 14  2016 wp-trackback.php
-rw-r--r--  1 wordpress www-data  3065 Aug 31  2016 xmlrpc.php
```

Can anybody provide me a hint why the installation does not work out of the box, and why the ftp user & pass is required?

Thanks,
Gerald

Comment: not sure but maybe the user apache is running as does not have write rights

Comment: set permissions to all files and directories.  Directories 755 and files 644, including the theme folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) See if the internal folder /theme is writable too.

2) Add
`define('FS_METHOD','direct');` to `wp-config.php`